Best root finding algorithm to use for this problem..
The following formula is used to find the strike, $K$, that achieves the maximum delta on a premium adjusted FX call option priced under black-76 model.
$$ g(K) = \sigma \sqrt{T} N(d_-(K))- n(d_-(K)) = 0 $$
where, $N$ is the cumulative standard normal distribution function, $n$ is the standard normal probability density function, $\sigma$ and $T$ and $F$, are known quantities and,
$$d_-(K) = \frac{\ln{(F/K)} -\sigma^2T/2}{\sigma \sqrt{T}}$$
Without any specific knowledge about an interval in which $K$ falls, which 1-variable root finding algorithm is likely to perform fastest and most reliably on this problem?

Use Newton's method to find the value of $x$ such that $\sigma\sqrt TN(x) - n(x) = 0$. While Newton's method can fail in general. $N$ and $n$ are well behaved functions where it will converge nicely, no matter what your starting value. Once you have the value $x$, the value of $K$ is can be calculated as $$K = Fe^{-x\sigma\sqrt T - \sigma^2T}$$.

Out of curiosity, do you have a sensible range of values for your known parameters (T, F and sigma)?

sigma is volatility, typically between 0.05 and 0.20, but can be closer to zero or higher. T is time to expiry, anywhere from 1 day (1/365) to 30 years (30.0). F is the forward exchange rate, for some currency pairs is very small, i.e. 0.001 and for some quite large, e.g. 1000.0.

Thank you - I’m asking just to make some experimenting here and there. Also, you have a PDF and a CDF of a normal distribution: do you have mean and standard deviation for those? Are they representing the same underlying distribution (I.e., if the CDF simply the integral of the PDF in your case?)

They are the standard normal N(0,1). The scaling is accounted for in the definiton of $d_-$.

I got all nerd-style with your question...
Preamble: I hope my math is OK.
Starting with the approach suggested by @Paul Sinclair, if we define $Z = \sigma \sqrt{T} $ (since both $\sigma$ and $T$ are constants), we have to solve the following "objective function":
$$G = \sigma \sqrt{T} N(x) - n(x) = Z \frac{1}{2} \left[1+\operatorname{erf}{\left(\frac{ x}{\sqrt{2}} \right)}\right] - \frac{ e^{- \frac{x^{2}}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
And then back-calculate $K$ using the inverse of your formula for $d$:
$$K = F e^{-x\sigma\sqrt{T} - \sigma^2T/2}$$
I thought about applying all the root-finder methods available in SciPy, just for fun. The function $G$ can be differentiated to any degree (as far as I can see), and since some of the root-finding tools in SciPy can use first- and second-derivatives, I had some more fun:
$$\frac{dG}{dx} = \frac{e^{-x^2/2}(x+Z)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
$$\frac{d^2G}{dx^2} = -\frac{e^{-x^2/2}(x^2+xZ-1)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$$
As for the implementation, I generated 5,000 log-spaced points for $Z$, varying $Z$ from $10^{-6}$ to 6, and applied 8 root-finding algorithms (Bisect, Brent H, Brent Q, Halley, Newton, Ridder, Secant, TOMS748).
First things first: all the algorithms converge, for all 5,000 points, to the same solution per point (i.e., at point 100 for $Z$ all root-finding solvers gave exactly the same zero). This is because the function $G$ is extremely well-behaved - below a graph of $N(x)$, $n(x)$ and $G$ (assuming $Z=\sigma\sqrt{T}=1$):

The actual roots of $G$ (varying $Z$ for these 5,000 points) look like this:

In terms of performances, I was expecting better from Newton's and Halley's algorithms - Newton's should have quadratic convergence rate and Halley's cubic. The graph below shows the average number of function calls for each algorithm:

However, you asked for the "fastest" - which may also mean "fastest in terms of CPU time". Here we go:

Looks to me that Bisect, Brent and Ridder may be implemented in C inside SciPy: I mean, 25 $\mu s$ is a very short time for a root-finding process.
If you need even more speed, implementing your "objective function" in Fortran and using any of the available Brent implementations (i.e., https://github.com/ivan-pi/zerobench), may give you a further 20%-50% speed-up.
Finally, using the inverse formula to calculate $K$, I get this graph for a number of combinations of $\sigma$ and $T$ (keeping $F = 1$ as it's just a multiplication constant for of $K$):

I have no clue whatsoever if those number for $K$ make any sense or not :-) . Hopefully you'll have a better grasp of the meaning of all these numbers and may be able to correct my math/understanding in case I have missed/misinterpreted something.
EDIT
After @Attack68 comments, the roots of the function $G(x)$ can be approximated/fitted quite nicely by an exponential formula.
Defining:
$$Z = \sigma \sqrt T $$
The fitted equation is:
$$Roots[G(Z)] \approx aZ^b + cZ^d + fZ^g$$
With the coefficients:
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
a=3.38777577683324710 & \\ 
b=-0.0321538987860638 & \\ 
c=-0.6749937815114762 & \\ 
d=1.08648555952878920 & \\ 
f=-3.0101764849574044 & \\ 
g=0.198384242124144070 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
Using that fitted formula, this is the graph of the roots of $G(Z)$ vs. the equation above:

In addition, by implementing in Fortran the methods for Newton, Halley and Jarratt (third-order) and feeding them as a starting point the value returned by the approximation function, I get this for the average number of function calls (note: the only differences are the addition of the Fortran implementations F_Halley, F_Jarrat and F_Newton):

So, between 2 to 3 function calls to get to the zero. With a ridiculously fast simulation time (note: elapsed time is now in $\mu s$):

This is less than 1 $\mu s$ on my machine to obtain the zero of the function to $10^{-14}$ precision.

Nice work! surprised by Newton and Halley too. I wonder if I might approximate the roots graph and use it to determine an initial point that is close to the actual solution that reduces iterations

That might be possible, yes, either by interpolating into the (now known) $G$ vs $\sigma \sqrt T$ points or by trying to fit a (unknown) curve through the zeros of $G$. That said, I’m not sure by how much you will be able to beat 25 $\mu s$ for a single run of Brent or Ridder…

@Attack68: please see the edit, it may answer your comment.

There we have it. 1us. I knew it could be done. Thx!
